# sending a post request apache and java

Tags: java, apache, http-post

I have this code block that sends a post request to one of my localhost ports:

```
public String request(String name){
        String responseString = null;

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userName", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("passWord","123455"));
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:2332/getData/postData");
        post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        post.setEntity(new StringEntity(URLEncodedUtils.format(params,"UTF-8"), HTTP.UTF_8));

        responseString = execute(post,params.toString());

        return responseString;
    }

    public String execute(HttpRequestBase requestBase, String params){
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = null;
        String responseString = "";
        try {
            LOG.info("Request Method:{}",requestBase.getMethod());
            LOG.info("Request Parameters:{}",params);

            response = httpClient.execute(requestBase);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseString;
    }
```

I think that this code block should work because I used a tutorial as a reference but whenever I run my application the value of responseString is null or the application doesn't show me any results. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Do you control the server? Does it write anything to the HTTP response?

Comment: yes my web application controls the server the expected response should be a data on a json format.

Comment: Can you print out the value of `entity`? `EntityUtils.toString(..)` should only return `null`, if that is `null`.

Comment: i tried to print the status code generated by the application and it returned a 302 status, so meaning the problem lies on the my other application that handles the server.

Comment: I would've thought `HttpClient` follows 302 responses automatically. You might have to configure that.